# No results in record set

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a temporary table being created from a query. From that table I am selecting the items and placing them in a specific order to display in a listbox. Everything works great until I try to add a where clause to my select statement.

What I'd like to do is, when I run the query that isn't working below, just have the variables return as "0".

I have tried to do an if statement that just makes my variable "0", but I still get the same "No Current Record" error.

The below query it works fine;

```vb
  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & currentTime & " Order By CVT, CVY, CVW, 
  AdjusterName"
```

But when I add in a where clause of <=1 then I get a "No Current Record" error. The second query is;

```vb
  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <=1 Order By 
  CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName"
```

When I run this second query I get a "No Current Record" error. This is where I'd like it to just display a zero instead.

Just in case it's needed, here is the entire function;

```vb
    If ClaimTypeCB = "MO" Then
        strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <=1 Order 
        By CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName"
    Else
        strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & currentTime & " Order By CVT, CVY, 
        CVW, AdjusterName"
    End If
        Set daoQueryResult = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

        daoQueryResult.MoveLast
        intRecordCount = daoQueryResult.RecordCount
        daoQueryResult.MoveFirst

    If intRecordCount = 0 Then
        intCVT = 0
    End If
```

(The above If Statement is where I tried to insert an If statement, but it didn't work, and I still get a "No Current Record" error.)

```vb
    If intRecordCount <> 0 Then
        With daoQueryResult
            Do While Not .EOF

                If IsNull(!CVT) Then
                    intCVT = 0
                Else
                    intCVT = !CVT
                End If

                If IsNull(!CVY) Then
                    intCVY = 0
                Else
                    intCVY = !CVY
                End If

                If IsNull(!CVW) Then
                    intCVW = 0
                Else
                    intCVW = (!CVW)
                End If

                AvailAdjList.AddItem !AdjusterName & "," & intCVT & "," & intCVY & "," & intCVW
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
    End If
```

I really just want CVT to return as zero if it is 0 or 1.

Comment: hi, did u try daoQueryResult.recordcount to get the number of rows returned ?

Comment: Can you Debug.Print your strQuery variable? There may be something off about the SQL statement you are trying to execute. There may be a reserved word or some punctuation in the query. What is the currentTime variable set to?

Comment: What are the names of all the columns of the table? And do you want 0 only in column CVT?

Comment: @ Luis I did try Debug.Print daoQueryResult.RecordCount and it returns a 0.

Comment: @ Eedz, If I run the query without the "WHERE CVT <=1" clause it runs just fine.

Comment: @forpas the column names are "CVT", "CVY", "CVW", and "AdjusterName". The CVT column is the only one that would need a zero. I only have this problem when CVT is zero and I use the "WHERE CVT <=1" clause. If I run it without that Where clause it works just fine, even if the results are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
strQuery = "SELECT CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <= 1 Order By CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName" _
         & " UNION ALL " _
         & "SELECT DISTINCT 0, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE NOT EXISTS " _
         & "(SELECT 1 FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <= 1)"
```

It uses `UNION ALL` so that if the 1st query does not return any rows, the 2nd query will return a row with values: `0, NULL, NULL, NULL`
I hope I have no typos.

Comment: I changed this up a bit to;                                                                                 
       strQuery = "SELECT CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <= 1 Order By CVT, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName" _
                & " UNION ALL " _
                & "SELECT DISTINCT 0, CVY, CVW, AdjusterName FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE NOT EXISTS " _
                & "(SELECT 1 FROM " & currentTime & " WHERE CVT <= 1)"                                                And this worked great

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```vb
Set daoQueryResult = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

you need to check for [Recordset.EOF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-eof-property-dao)

```vb
With daoQueryResult
    If .EOF Then
        intRecordCount = 0
    Else
        .MoveLast
        intRecordCount = .RecordCount
        .MoveFirst
    End If
End With
```

Though from your code you don't seem to really need `RecordCount`.

You could simply start with `Do While Not .EOF`

Comment: This fixed the error, but now no results at all display. What I need is for it to display the users name (AdjusterName) and then just zeros next to their names if there are no current records.